# SQL where syntax error with trigger

Tags: mysql, sql

```
create trigger cal_retweet before insert on T
for each row begin 
set NEW.retweet_change = NEW.retweet_count - retweet_count where id_str = NEW.id_str
end
```

SQL said there is syntax error near "where id_str = NEW.id_str"

My table looks like this. Where id_str is a unique identifier for a specific tweet. Since I am inserting 50 tweets from a single user every minute, there would be many same id_str. What I want to look at is the change of retweet_count every minute. tweeted_at is when the user tweeted, created_at is when this data is inserted into my database. I want to generate retweet_change for each new data inserted into the database compared to the same old tweet (into the column retweet_change). How should I write the trigger?

[image]

After reading some of your comments I changed my code to :

```
create trigger cal_retweet before update on T
for each row 
begin 
set NEW.retweet_change = NEW.retweet_count - OLD.retweet_count;
end;
```

There is still syntax error

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Edited

Comment: The trigger is already acting on a single row (within the loop); I don't think you need the `WHERE` at all.

Comment: Where are you expecting the not-"NEW" field values to come from?

Comment: your where keyword is the problem you are processing one row at a time that is what the for each row does. i would recomend reading up on the documetnation for triggers

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: when I delete the WHERE, the error becomes you have an error near 'end'

Comment: This should be an `UPDATE` trigger I think, which would give you access to `OLD`. In order to do your calculation, you need to know the before value. `set NEW.retweet_change = NEW.retweet_count - OLD.retweet_count;`. You also need to use proper semicolons to delimit the statements.

Comment: No need for `end` and you are missing a semicolon at the end of the set statement. You really should check out the mysql manual for its syntax...

Comment: @Shadow why is there no need for end? The example in the manual has one

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ I made the changes but still got error

Comment: @Dylan: You need an `END` to pair with any `BEGIN`. You don't need the `BEGIN` really since you have a single-line statement, but some believe it's good practice to always use them. Please provide exact errors messages in your updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with this trigger.

1. You have some syntax errors. You need proper semicolons to delimit your statements.
2. You have a `WHERE` statement that is out of place (and actually not needed). You are acting on only a single row at a time, you don't have to match on the `id_str`.
3. In order to factor in a calculation using an existing value from the row, you need access to the `OLD` keyword. For that, you need a trigger that happens on `UPDATE`, not `INSERT`. On `INSERT`, the `retweet_change` is simply the same as `retweet_count`; you could alter your `INSERT` statement to fix that problem.
4. You may need to explicitly add a statement delimiter as per the comments below.

So all together, I think this trigger should look like:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER cal_retweet BEFORE UPDATE ON T
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN 
    SET NEW.retweet_change = NEW.retweet_count - OLD.retweet_count;
  END;//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: When using this version, I get : Error Code: 1362. Updating of NEW row is not allowed in after trigger

Comment: @Dylan: You are correct; it should still happen `BEFORE`. Any difference with my updated answer?

Comment: Depending on your IDE you may need to put backticks around the entity names and/or use preface your statement with a DELIMITER definition.

Comment: If you're using `BEGIN...END` the delimiter after END should be different than the one used to terminate the statements in the trigger's body.

Comment: @Cory, Thank you! It is the problem of the DELIMITER, after I add that I met another issue described here: https://techtavern.wordpress.com/2013/06/17/mysql-triggers-and-amazon-rds/     it is solved now though.

Comment: @Cory, Although there is no more syntax error, I just tested on that trigger, it doesn't behave what I expected it to do as described above. Do you have any idea on this? Could it be that I used Python to insert rows into Mysql?

Comment: @Dylan: I would simply ask a new question; post the valid trigger definition that isn't doing what you expect; show some before and after results. If you think you have an issue in your Python code, post the relevant part of that as well. MySQL is not my normal wheelhouse, so even this was a bit beyond my knowledge (if you couldn't tell).